# cpp program returns core dumped while reading csv file

Tags: c++, csv, file, vector

I am trying to make  a program that reads csv file and set the format in a 2d vector of string so as to use in my project.It says nothing and gives strange errors saying core dumped.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<fstream>
    using namespace std;
    class pk{
        public:
        vector <string> func1(string a){
            string temp="";
            int k=0;
            vector<string> finalone;
            for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++){
                if (a[i]==','){
                    finalone.push_back(temp);
                    temp="";
                    k=0;
                    continue;
                }
                temp[k]=a[i];
                k+=1;
    
    
            }
            return finalone;
    
        }
    };
    int main(){
        fstream f1;
        string line;
       vector< vector <string>> p;
        f1.open("pk.txt");
        while (f1){
    getline(f1,line);
    pk puj;
    p.push_back(puj.func1(line));
    
        }
f1.close();
    
    
    }
```

here is the error:
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:773:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream&>’
and it gives more strange errors saying core dumped at last.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot obtain the number of characters in `std::string` by `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`. You should use `a.size()` instead.

Also `temp[k]=a[i];` is bad because the string `temp` has only zero characters and it will lead to out-of-range access. You should use `temp.push_back(a[i]);` to append a character to `std::string`.

References:

- [std::basic_string - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

  - `std::string` is an alias of `std::basic_string<char>`.
- [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::size, std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::length - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)
- [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::push_back - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)

Comment: I have corrected that still it says core dumped